# Is it possible to debug what images CNN guessed wrong during training or evaluation? Tensorflow/Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am currently training a model to classify images to, say, 10 classes. I have a dataset of 10k images (1k per class). During training, NN was able to achieve ~99.6% accuracy, which, in my understanding, means that out of 10000 images 40 items were misclassified.

**Can i somehow know exactly what image (or at least batch) caused mistakes**? I want to do so to visually check what type if images causes mistakes. I suppose they would be sort of outliers, so when I figure out their features, i could augment my dataset with similar images to improve accuracy.

I can simply run 'predict' over my initial dataset after training, but maybe there is more elegant and less time-consuming way to find culprits.

If it matters, I've got my dataset from directory with tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom callback, so that after each epochs to print out the indexes of the misclassified images, but that would require to re-train the model.

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback
import numpy as np

class CustomCallback(Callback):
def __init__(self, x_data, y_data, batch_size):
    super().__init__()
    self.x_data = x_data
    self.y_data = y_data
    self.batch_size = batch_size

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    y_pred = self.model.predict(self.x_data)

    # Compare the predicted labels to the true labels
    indices = np.where(np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1) != np.argmax(self.y_data, axis=-1))[0]

    # print the indices of the wrong labeled images
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1} - Misclassified images indices: {indices.tolist()}")
```

Now add it to callbacks in model.fit

```
   callback = CustomCallback(x_train, y_train, batch_size)
   history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, callbacks=[callback])
```